# How to visualise the feature distribution in each StratifiedKFold

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to visualise the distribution of each feature per fold to check whether all folds have a roughly representative distribution of each other.

So far I'm using this code from an existing tutorial, but unsure how to find the features in each set and plot the distributions without iterating over the results for each fold.

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 42)
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(features, labels):
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = features[train_index],
features[test_index], labels[train_index], labels[test_index]         
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For each fold I would like to output a histogram for each feature per fold (e.g. 5 features = 5 histograms per fold).

Any information on how to do this would be helpful .

Comment: You mean, plot histograms for `X_train` features in each of your CV fold?

Comment: Exactly, or at least create data frames for each X_train so that I can then plot the features.